# Resize filter for Apple compressor

Tags: video, quality, compressor

I use Apple Compressor to generate 60fps movie clips from sequences of PNG images. I use the HEVC coded with transparency. The resolution of the output movie is the same as of the input pictures, so no resizing is done.

Is it safe to ignore the Resize filter?

Comment: Does using it without actually resizing make a difference (in file size, output size, visible quality)?

Comment: Seems similar to a previous question posted just a bit ago. As I suggested there, make a test input file then check the output files based on what changes you make. Choose the “best” settings for your situation.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes indeed, but the previous question was closed. So now I ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resize filter only takes effect if the image is being resized, which you are not doing, since your export resolution is the same as the input.

E.g *neared pixel* option.:

> Nearest Pixel (Fastest): Samples the nearest neighboring pixel when resizing an image.

In general this setting determines how the pixels are being calculated, e.g. if you resize from 4K to 2.7K or similar.

You can read more about all the settings at [apple support](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/compressor/cpsr45ce0ac5/mac).

---

As mentioned in another post in a comment, I would advise you to ask these video questions in a film/video forum. They will most likely give you more detailed and technical answers than here, since although you are using an Apple product, *how to export videos* is probably one of the most interesting/most discussed questions, because it determines what the actual audience will be able to see.